# error using scp in pexpect script

Tags: python, scp, pexpect

im trying to make a backup toll that reads data from xml file and make a copy of the back up file
the xml file contains all the device data like so:

```
<data>
    <devices>
        <device name='cisco' ip='10.10.10.10' uname='username' password='passpass' backup_make='Write memory' backup_location_device='nvram:/startup-config' backup_location='idan/backup_fiels/backup1.cfg' ></device>     
        </devices>
</data>
```

i use the data to connect in ssh like so,  its working good :

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('xmlfile.xml')
devicelist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('device')

    address=('ssh ',devicelist[0].attributes['uname'].value,'@',devicelist[0].attributes['ip'].value)
    password = (devicelist[0].attributes['password'].value)

    ssh_device = pexpect.spawn(address)
    ssh_device.expect('.assword:')
    .
    .
    .
```

but when i do the same for scp im geting an error

```
backup = ('scp ',devicelist[0].attributes['uname'].value,'@',devicelist[0].attributes['ip'].value,':',devicelist[0].attributes['backup_location_device'].value,' test.cfg')

ssh_device = pexpect.spawn(backup)
ssh_device.expect('.assword:')
.
.
.
```

when im running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmltest.py", line 34, in <module>
    backup_make = pexpect.spawn(backup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 485, in __init__
    self._spawn(command, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 590, in _spawn
    'executable: %s.' % self.command)
pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: scp Netadmn9@10.10.10.10:nvram:/startup-config test.cfg.
```

and the floowing command is working too:

```
backup = ('scp Netadmn9@10.106.11.111:nvram:/startup-config HSBU1a1_idan.cfg')

ssh_device = pexpect.spawn(backup)
ssh_device.expect('.assword:')
.
.
.
```

can any one help ?
thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pexpect is expecting a command and then a list of arguments, so it needs breaking up.

try:

```
backup = "scp %s@%s:%s test.cfg" % (devicelist[0].attributes['uname'].value,devicelist[0].attributes['ip'].value,devicelist[0].attributes['backup_location_device'].value)

split_command = shlex.split(backup)
ssh_device = pexpect.spawn(split_command)
```

On a side note, if you setup public private key login then you wont need pexpect to do the backup you can use subprocess call.

read [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/).

```
split_command = shlex.split(backup)
subprocess.call(split_command)
```

I have added a string format line instead of the tuple you generated.

This should be sensibly split by shlex.split()

Comment: im getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmltest.py", line 35, in <module>
    split_command = shlex.split(backup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 124, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'
and yes the 'regular' scp command works

Comment: yes if i write 
address=('scp Netadmn9@10.10.10.10:nvram:/startup-config HSBU1a1_idan.cfg')

Comment: ok,so it is a tokenising issue:  I have put a string constructor in the answer.. sorry it goes off the page but it can wrap on commas in your code.

Comment: you will probably have to replace the static file name with a var as well :) "scp %s@%s:%s %s"  and add it to the tuple

Comment: tried that im getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable and thanks for your help !

Comment: the error is when i try to print the veriables as string liko so :scp %s@%s:%s %s

Comment: "foo %s bar %s coffee"("blah","asdf")
but it should be:

"foo %s bar %s coffee"%("blah","asdf")

found the problem thankes !

Comment: So did I answer your Question?